# PYTHON : How repeat task?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape a page with lazy loading, so I use below codes, the same lines of codes needs to be repeated 4 to 5 times to all products listed/loaded.

How do you simplify this codes so I don't have to repeat my codes  ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

driver.get("https://www.tropicanawholesale.com/shop-by-category/diet-and-weight-management/")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(15)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(15)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(15)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("product-listing-row")
raw_data = []
for ii in elem:
    pname = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-name').text
    print('pname: ' + pname)
    psku = ii.find_element_by_class_name('product-code').text
    print('psku: ' + psku)
    thumb = ii.find_element_by_class_name('scaleAll').get_attribute('src')
    print('thumb: ' + thumb)
    link = ii.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
    print('address: ' + link)
    raw_data_elem = {'Product_Name': pname,
        'Product_SKU': psku,
        'Product_ImageURL': thumb,
        'Product _URL': link}
    #add row to list
    raw_data.append(raw_data_elem)
    df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['Product_Name', 'Product_SKU',
        'Product_ImageURL', 'Product _URL'])
    df.to_csv (r'/Users/reezalaq/PycharmProjects/wholesale/data.csv')
```

Comment: .... first leasson in programing, use functions

Comment: Read about loops.

Comment: @Reezal2040 Where is your _...trying to scrape..._ related code?

Comment: @ DebanjanB just added

Comment: My solution is,  load page, get result elements, while (codition checking size previous and current elements are equal): scroll, get elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

def run_script():
    driver.get("https://www.tropicanawholesale.com/shop-by-category/diet-and-weight- 
    management/")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

count = 0
while count < 5:
     run_script()
     count+=1
     time.sleep(15)
```

Comment: No, that is not similar to his code, the scroll is cause website have infinite scroll, driver.get() is only done 1 time... He should be able to know when to stop scroll. I have code for all this stuff

Comment: thanks! it works but I have remove driver.get from the function so it won't reload everytime.